# Pre-filter set without any effect in List Fabrik Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, filter, fabrik

I have a List "Document Manager" defined in Fabrik module in Joomla and I want to pre-filter the documents from the list, in order to show only the documents belonging to the currently logged in user.

For example: if Testuser is logged in, in Document Manager list, I want to see only the documents created by the Testuser. I have attached two screenshots for more details.

Somehow it looks like a script in the background is resetting those pre-filters, but I can't find it.

I checked also if the Menu Item "Document Manager" has any pre-filter set, but it doesn't.

[image: Fabrik_List]

[image: Pre-filter]